# Using PigServer to run mapreduce jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I want to use the PigServer java class to run pig scripts on a remote hadoop cluster. At the moment I am using the cloudera cdh4.4.0 distribution for testing pusposes. I'm running my java program from within the cloudera VM.

The directory with the hadoop config files is included in the classpath.

When I run the same script in map reduce mode in shell it works just fine. Thanks in advance for your answer.

The java code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020");
props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost.localdomain:8021");

PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);

pigServer.registerQuery("batting = load './Batting.csv' using PigStorage(',');");
pigServer.registerQuery("runs_raw = FOREACH batting GENERATE $0 as playerID, $1 as year, $8 as runs;");
pigServer.registerQuery("runs = FILTER runs_raw BY runs > 0;");
pigServer.registerQuery("grp_data = GROUP runs by (year);");
pigServer.registerQuery("max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp, MAX(runs.runs) as max_runs;");
pigServer.registerQuery("join_max_run = JOIN max_runs by ($0, max_runs), runs by (year,runs);");
pigServer.registerQuery("join_data = FOREACH join_max_run GENERATE $0 as year, $2 as playerID, $1 as runs;");
pigServer.store("join_data", "join_data");
```

I also added the following maven dependency

`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
 </dependency>`

Upon running my java program I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation).
        log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
        *Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Unable to check name hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera*
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1608)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1547)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:518)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:531)
        at MainTestPigServer.main(MainTestPigServer.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
        Caused by: Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 1, column 10> pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1600)
        ... 9 more
        Caused by:
<line 1, column 10> pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:835)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3236)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1315)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:799)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:517)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:392)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:184)
        ... 10 more
        Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.datastorage.DataStorageException: ERROR 6007: Unable to check name hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.isContainer(HDataStorage.java:207)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.asElement(HDataStorage.java:128)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.asElement(HDataStorage.java:138)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserUtils.getCurrentDir(QueryParserUtils.java:91)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:827)
        ... 16 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).; Host Details : local host is: "localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost.localdomain":8020;
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at $Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at $Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1397)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.isContainer(HDataStorage.java:200)
        ... 20 more
        Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
        at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:89)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readTag(CodedInputStream.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1398)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.<init>(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto$1.parsePartialFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:1487)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:200)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:241)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:253)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:259)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.protobuf.RpcHeaderProtos$RpcResponseHeaderProto.parseDelimitedFrom(RpcHeaderProtos.java:2364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:891)

Process finished with exit code 1
```